# How to order a Django Rest Framework ManyToMany related field?

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-rest-framework

I have a Django Rest Framework application with the following (simplified) `models.py`:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    ...

class Album(models.Model):
    ...
    photos = models.ManyToManyField(Photo, through='PhotoInAlbum', related_name='albums')

class PhotoInAlbum(models.Model):

    photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)

    order = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['album', 'order']
```

And in my `serializers.py`, I have the following:

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ...
    photos = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField('photos', many=True)
```

My question is, how can I have `AlbumSerializer` return the photos ordered by the field `order`?

Answer (score 9):

The best solution to customise the queryset is using  `serializers.SerializerMethodField`, but what shezi's reply is not exactly right. You need to return `serializer.data` from `SerializerMethodField`. So the solution should be like this:

```
class PhotoInAlbumSerializer(serialisers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PhotoInAlbum


class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # ...

    photos = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_photos_list')

    def get_photos_list(self, instance):
        photos = PhotoInAlbum.objects\
            .filter(album_id=instance.id)\
            .order_by('order')\
            .values_list('photo_id', flat=True)

        return PhotoInAlbumSerializer(photos, many=True, context=self.context).data
```

Comment: In case the `PhotoInAlbumSerializer` makes use of something in the context, you should change the last line into `PhotoInAlbumSerializer(photos, many=True, context=self.context).data`

Comment: This is not a solution if the field also has to be writable.

Answer (score 5):

It looks as if the RelatedManager that handles the relationship for ManyToManyFields does not respect ordering on the through model.

Since you cannot easily add an ordering parameter to the serializer field, the easiest way to achieve ordering is by using a serializer method:

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.modelSerializer):
    # ...

    photos = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_photos_list')

    def get_photos_list(self, instance):
        return PhotoInAlbum.objects\
            .filter(album_id=instance.id)\
            .order_by('order')\
            .values_list('photo_id', flat=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the easiest way is to do this in your `AlbumView` or `AlbumViewSet`.
You can do this by [filtering](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering) - in this case you should define a `get_queryset` method in your `AlbumViewSet`.

Anyway, this is a good solution as long as you only GET the data. If you want to have POST and PUT methods working with ordering the photos, you can do it in two ways:

- **stay with `ManyToMany` relation** - patch the `create` method in `AlbumViewSet` and `__create_items` and `restore_object` method in `AlbumSerializer`

or

- **replace it with something more sophisticated** - use [django-sortedm2m](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-sortedm2m) field.

Note that the second solution does not mess with `AlbumViewSet` (and even `AlbumSerializer`!) - ordering logic stays in the relation field code.